# PHP Google Classroom API list_classes

Tags: php, google-classroom

I am having trouble with my Google API integration using PHP.

The code below will pull the classes, but it pulls them all (ACTIVE,ARCHIVED,ETC...).  I only want the ACTIVE CLASSES.

The problem is when I add the `courseStates` parameter it says it does not exist.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
            $courses = '';

            $optParams = array(
//none of these seem to work
              //'courseStates' => 'ACTIVE',
              //'courseState' => 'ACTIVE',
              //'CourseStates' => 'ACTIVE',
              'pageSize' => 50,
              'studentId' => $user_email
            );
            $results = $service->courses->listCourses($optParams);

            if (count($results->getCourses()) == 0) {
             // print "No courses found.\n";
            } else {
             // print "Courses:\n";
              foreach ($results->getCourses() as $course) {
                                $courses .= $course->getName()."<br />";//." ". $course->getId();

                //printf("%s (%s)\n", $course->getName(), $course->getId());
              }
            }
```

The method is here, but none of the options shown work
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list

Answer (score 1):

```
  $results = $service->courses->listCourses($optParams);
if (count($results->getCourses()) == 0) {
    // print "No courses found.\n";
} else {
    // print "Courses:\n"; 
    
    $insert_array_fill = '';
    $select_array_fill = '';
    foreach ($results->getCourses() as $course) {
        // 
        //echo "<hr>";
        if(strcmp($course->getCourseState(), 'ACTIVE') == 0){
            
            $courses .= $course->getName()." - ".$course->getId()." - ".$course->getAlternateLink()." - ".$course->getOwnerId()."<br />";//." ". $course->getId();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected solution is incorrect.
The problem is that you misspelled the key (*courseState* instead of *courseState**s***, missing **s**).

Should be -

```
'courseStates'  => 'ACTIVE'
```

This answer is relevant for version Google API v2.4.0.

Answer (score -1):

The variable [CourseState](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#resource:-course) is of type `Enum` and not `String` and therefore, it must be access as an `enum` and not as a `string`. Add the following to `optParams`:

```
'courseState' => 'courseState::ACTIVE',
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I must be doing something wrong that killed the API

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That didn't seem to fix it.  When I add that line I am not seeing results anymore
`$optParams = array(
 'courseState' => 'courseState::ACTIVE',
'teacherId' => $UI_username
);`

Comment: @MichaelKeough did you ever find a solution to this. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @firenemus unfortunately I didn't find a great answer.  Long story short I can't call the Google API with only active perimeters.  I have to pull everything and then filter it with conditional statements.  I don't mind sharing.  The solution works but I feel it's less efficient than it should be.

Comment: @MichaelKeough if you wouldn't mind, I very much appreciate seeing how you're filtering it. It's driving me crazy and Google's PHP documentation is far from adequate.

Comment: This solution is not correct, not for v2.4.0 at least.
The way to go is - `'courseStates'  => 'ACTIVE'`